# Прослушка нескольких сокетов на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сервер не получает соединение от второго, третьего и т.д. клиентов. Почему и как это исправить?

```
#клиент
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 50562))
s.send(b'msg recieved')
print('Done')
input()
```

```
#сервер
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 50562))
s.listen(5)
print('Server started')
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    for x in conn, addr:
        print('Conn')
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data)
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что цикл ждет окончания выполнения "recv".  А "recv" является блокирующей функцией.

Answer (score 0):

Пример асинхронного кода

```
import socket
from select import select

to_read = {} 

tasks = []

def server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 5001))
    server_socket.listen()

    while True:
        yield('read', server_socket)
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print('conected...', addr)


def event_loop():

     while any([tasks, to_read]):

         while not tasks:
            ready_to_read,  _ = select(to_read, [])

            for sock in ready_to_read:
                tasks.append(to_read.pop(sock))

        try:
            task = tasks.pop(0)

            reason, sock = next(task)

            if reason == 'read':
                to_read[sock] = task

        except StopIteration:
            print('done')

tasks.append(server())
event_loop()
```